# How do I unwrap an over-complex mesh?

Tags: uv

[image]

The above is the part of my mesh(done by Dyntopo in sculpting) and I'm having a real hard time unwrapping it. I tried the add-on(Downloaded somewhere, not inside blender) that helps UV mapping in squares but that lags hard and it ended up as a linear single line UV. I spent 10 minutes just for adding three seems to the mesh and it's too backbreaking. Help pls :C

Comment: either deal with this or retopo then uv unwrap it.
you could use a simpler object and copy the uv from it and transfer it to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally such mesh should be retopologized.

But anyway if for whaterever reason you don't want or cannot do a propper retopology, you can just use Blender's automatic unwrapping features.

When you select your mesh in edit mode and press <kbd>U</kbd>, it brings up the UV mapping menu with plenty options.

[image: UV Mapping menu]

In red I marked the automatic unwrap methods. They each automatically unwrap your selected mesh following different sets of rules and eventually with some options you can have a hand on. They each have some ideal situations they're good at.

The one you might like here is the Smart UV Project. It basically makes seams when adjacent faces form an angle superior to a chosen value (the default is 66).

[image: Smart UV Project menu]

You can click that and see how it goes. If there are too many cuts, lower the angle limit, vice versa. Try to find the right balance between the number of islands and the obtained distortion. If it's not an important mesh (which I guess it is if you don't retopologize it), you don't have to spend time on that, just make something that looks ok from afar and move on.

Learn more in the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/uv/unwrapping/mapping_types.html#smart-uv-project).

Comment: I don't know how to retopologize a given mesh.. I don't even know what it is. The Dyntopo thing is just what I've seen in a tutorial and just followed through.

Comment: And after using the smart UV project I also have a problem that when I'm painting on the mesh(I'm texture painting on the mesh in blender) there are specific parts that just cannot be different each other. So for example if I were to paint at area A, area B also changes, They are interconnected,

Comment: they must share the same UV shell, but yep you need to do a retopo for Unwarping easier but it depends on the object....

Comment: Makin a retopology is basically making a new version of your model but by manually making each face following some logics in order to make a mesh that's lightweight, defines it's shapes with a minimum of memory usage, easy to deform (if animated), easy to unwrap, ... You might want to search tutorials on that. It's not something you usually do by clicking a button (unless you work on some models that's not important like a background rock seen from afar).